# I need show a modal if these strings contains the page into a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, simplemodal

For example, i have 3 strings to verify if contains in a page, if this strings are not in this page the modal doesn't load on page, and if string contains on page load this opens this modal.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fl-product-ref').load(function(){
      var lightBox = $('.skuReference');
      switch(false) {
        case (lightBox.find('LNC-L4139800')):
        case (lightBox.find('LNC-L6669601')):
        case (lightBox.find('LNC-L6669600')):
            lightBox.removeClass('hidden').addClass('visible');
            break;
        default:
            lightBox.addClass('hidden');
            break; 
      }
    });
}
```

```html
<span class="fl-product-ref">
  <div class="skuReference">LNC-L4139800</div>
</span>

<div class="skuModal hidden">
  This is the modal!
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <style type="text/css">
        .hidden{
      visibility :hidden;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<span class="fl-product-ref">
  <div class="skuReference">LNC-L4139800</div>
  <div class="skuReference">LNC-L4139800</div>
  <div class="skuReference">LNC-L6669601</div>
  <div class="skuReference">LNC-L4139800</div>
</span>

<div class="skuModal hidden">
  This is the modal!
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   // $('.fl-product-ref').load(function(){
      var arr = $('.skuReference').map(function(index , val){ return $(val).text()});
      //["LNC-L4139800", "LNC-L4139800", "LNC-L6669601", "LNC-L4139800"]

      switch(true) {
        case ($.inArray("LNC-L4139800", arr) !== -1):
        case ($.inArray("LNC-L6669601", arr) !== -1):
        case ($.inArray("LNC-L6669600", arr) !== -1):
            $('.skuModal').removeClass('hidden').addClass('visible');
            break;
        default:
            $('.skuModal').addClass('hidden');
            break; 
      }
    //});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `switch` statement uses strict equals (`===`) to match it's expression with a case clause.

> A switch statement first evaluates its expression. It then looks for the first case clause whose expression evaluates to the same value as the result of the input expression (using strict comparison, ===)

jQuery's find doesn't return a boolean value, so strict equals won't work in this case.

Comment: that is only part of the issue ... `find()` is used to query elements, not text

Comment: It's contingent not a necessity, you can still use `==`

Answer (score 0):

I used the jQuery `:contains()` selector.

Check my jsFiddle here: [Check if page contains certain strings of text, if so, do something](https://jsfiddle.net/etmargallo/dwj4y63b/4/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (($('body:contains("LNC-L4139800")').length > 0)
         && ($('body:contains("LNC-L6669601")').length > 0)
         && ($('body:contains("LNC-L6669600")').length > 0)) {
               alert("launch modal");
    }
});
```

Learn more about the `:contains()` selector here: https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/ Important note: **The text must have matching case to be selected.**

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      var needleProducts= ['LNC-L4139800','LNC-L6669601','LNC-L6669600'];
      var products = [];
      var showModal = true;
      $('.skuReference').each(function(){
            products.push($(this).text());
      });
      for(var i = 0; i < needleProducts.length; i++){
          if(find(products,  needleProducts[i]) === -1){
             showModal = false;
          }
      }

      if(showModal){
            $('.skuModal').removeClass('hidden').addClass('visible');
      } else {
          $('.skuModal').addClass('hidden'); 
      }
});

//crossbrowser method
function find(array, value) {
  if (array.indexOf) { // if method exist
    return array.indexOf(value);
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] === value) return i;
  }

  return -1;
}
```